# Is SSH with pub key authentication AND a password at every login possible?

Tags: ssh, password

Is it possible to configure SSH to have public key authentication *and* require a password at every login on Ubuntu?  I think the password would be an good extra layer of security.  I’ve seen a few older posts on other forums where people asked about that, but there didn’t seem to be any real solutions to it back then.  I find that difficult to believe though.